# 'page' displaying in simple form action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a simple form for an edit action.
However in the html, the action is `/events/page/22`. 
When i submit, it obviously says that the route doesn't exist.
I would expect the action to be just `/events/22`, so i have no idea why/where `page` has come from? I have nothing in the code to do with `page` (other than pagination...?)
The class on the simple form is 'edit_event', so i think that is ok.
My routes are just using resources, so they are all available.
I haven't seen anyone with this problem before.
Below is the start of the simple form in the edit view (which is in a form partial).
Thanks

```html
  <%= simple_form_for event, url: events_path(event) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Could you add the view of the relevant form to the question?

Comment: should it be `event_path(event)`? (singular event)